# Notepad++ doesn't highlight matching braces in Perl?

Tags: perl, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I have been using Ultraedit 16 for Perl editing. 
I'm thinking about migrating to [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and gave it a try.

Here's how Ultraedit does highlighting. The cursor is on the last brace, and the matching first brace is highlighted:
[image: y]

Here's how Notepad++ highlights the same code. Cursor in the same place, but no highlight on the matching first brace.

[image]

I've looked through the configuration and searched elsewhere, it seems that the highlighting should be possible, but I'm not finding it.

Comment: Bracket matching for Perl works [for me](http://imgbox.com/BDkfx6XM) ... though it is not a block like UltraEdit. Check the options in Preferences => Highlighting.

Comment: Thanks! Found it after more digging - Settings => Style Configurator => Global Styles => Brace Highlight style.  I can set a background style there to make the matched brace more visible.

Comment: YOu might want to take a look at https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-ide/. Komodo is a professional IDE with debugging and other features built in, made by the same company that makes ActivePerl (for Windows), and runs on Windows and Linux. It's now completely free if you make an account. It's less lean than one of the editors you're using, but much more powerful, and well better suited for Perl than Atom and VSCode wihtout a ton of plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it after more digging - Settings => Style Configurator => Global Styles => Brace Highlight style. I can set a background style there to make the matched brace more visible.

One possible result:
[image]